# Sound from DVD very low in MPlayer, other sounds normal

Tags: 12.04, sound, dvd-audio

Seems to be related to MPlayer playback only. VLC sound levels are fine.

If I play a local or youtube video then sound is normal, much louder than the DVD. 
The DVD has Dolby Digital 5.1.
I've connected my amp through the headphone jack and the line out jack, both similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check and adjust the output volume for Mplayer to match the other applications' output levels. (Have Mplayer outputting audio when you go to set it, or you will see the same message as in the screenshot below.)

System Settings -> Sound -> Applications:

[image: Sound settings]